# How do I use a ViewPager in conjuction with bottom tab?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I'm trying to create a MainActivity with 3 tabs. In the first tab there is a ViewPager that displays a card that can be changed by swiping left/right. The second and third tabs each contains a simple Fragment displaying a TextView.

I'm using roughike/BottomBar and ncapdevi/FragNav library to achieve this. The Problem is FragNav doesn't work if the container is a viewpager and the card fragment doesn't work properly if I use something like a FrameLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is looking for a solution to encapsulate a fragment inside a tab navbar of any kind, I kinda have a workaround. In later android API (IIRC 21) fragments inside fragments is allowed so you can ignore this but for previous api levels you can try to hide the views instead using

```
view.hide();
```